# Google Maps - Follow Path Of Travel

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am working with a security company that has a patrol car travel around a neighborhood.  Every 30 seconds, they record a GPS coordinate/point which I can download and use.  I'm trying to map a 'path of travel' for the patrol vehicle using Google Maps API.

I understand how to map (marker) all the points using the Google Maps v3 API.  I also understand how I can do a driving route between a few points using directionsService.  According to Google and StackOverflow, the maximum number of waypoints is 26.

The problem is that I have dozens of these points (1 hour = 120 points).  I can't just draw a polyline between the points because I need it to show the path of travel on the actual street - not as the crow flies between 2 points.  Also, I don't have 10K to purchase an Enterprise license.

Any ideas on how this might be accomplished or am I SOL?  Can you draw 120 multiple 'routes' on the same map?  Speed is not important here.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can you draw 120 multiple 'routes' on the same map?*

You can. When you want to draw the routes by using the DirectionsRenderer you must use a separate `DirectionsRenderer`-instance for each route.

Another approach: request the routes via the DirectionsService, but use a custom `Polyline` to draw the route. Each time you get a new route you'll only have to push the points of the new route to the path of the polyline.

Comment: Thx Dr. - I will try both methods.  Do you have any sample code you could share on how to use a custom Polyline to draw the route?  I assume I will need to pass an array of coordinates built from a route somehow?

Comment: OK - confirmed that your first solution works (separate DirectionsRenderer instance).  Thx!!

Comment: here a demo for the 2nd approach: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/fx3nX/  (the important parts of the code are commented)